# Why is the request routed to getAction by default > Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am working on a zend framework application, and to my surprise, the default routing is not working as expected. This is my url:

**`http://localhost/zend_app/public/index/test`**

and it is supposed to route to the **index** controller > **test** action in **default** module. But it is not working as expected.

When i printed the request params, i got the action as "**get**" and id as "**test**".

```
array (
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'get',
  'id' => 'test',
  'module' => 'default'
)
```

FYI, I configured certain regex routes in my bootstrap file like this:

```
protected function _initRestRoute()
    {
        require_once 'Zend/Controller/Front.php';    
        require_once 'Zend/Controller/Router/Route.php';

        $ctrl  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $ctrl->getRouter();

$router->addRoute(
            'route2',
            new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                                            'api/([^-]*)/([^-]*)\.([^-]*)', 
                                            array(
                                            'action' => 'index'
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                                1 => 'module',
                                                2 => 'controller'
                                            )
        ));

}
```

But none of the routes match my url above.
I could not understand what could be the issue.

Comment: Do you have any custom routes?

Comment: Yes, i have defined some custom routes in my "default" module's bootstrap, using Regex Route. But i hope none of those patterns match the above url.

Comment: @dskanth. Could you post the routes?

Comment: @Marcin: I have updated my question with a sample route. All routes begin with the "api/" pattern. But i hope none of those custom routes match my url: http://localhost/zend_app/public/index/test

Comment: It is probably some problem with your custom routes. Maybe incorrect regex. Zend request object works as expected.

Comment: @dskanth. It seems that ZF thinks that 'test' is an id parameter for 'get' action. If you don't have any other routes other than form api then  I don't know whats happening.

Comment: I could manage to make the default functionality work, by commenting out the following line (related to the routing) in my application.ini: **resources.router.routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read carefully the notes under [Zend Rest Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest).

Zend Rest Route is designed to simplify RESTful applications, and routes requests based on the URL and request *method*.

In this case, you are issuing a GET request for item 'test' under the index controller.

Comment: But i dont understand why the default zend routing is not working here with my url. Because i suppose a url pattern in Zend would be matched (by default) to: **....../controller/action**. And my url does not match any regex route too... (and even there, i have specified action as index, not get)

Comment: I think Zend_Rest_Route takes precedent over all other routes (it is tested for matches first) but you'll have to read the docs carefully and test it.

Comment: Yes, i feel the same. When i comment out the line (hope it is not needed though) **resources.router.routes.rest.type = Zend_Rest_Route** in my application.ini, it works as expected :)